# Why my select doesn't display the data that I'm giving to it? Angular 10

Tags: html, json, angular, select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm having troubles with a select in my html template of my angular project.
The thing is I have a JSON with all countries.

Languages Interface

```
export interface Country{
    name:string
    code:string
  }
```

countries.json

```
[
    {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
    {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"},
    {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
    {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
    {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"},
    {"name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"},
    {"name": "Angola", "code": "AO"},
    {"name": "Anguilla", "code": "AI"},
    {"name": "Antarctica", "code": "AQ"},
    {"name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "code": "AG"},
    {"name": "Argentina", "code": "AR"},
    {"name": "Armenia", "code": "AM"},
    {"name": "Aruba", "code": "AW"},
    {"name": "Australia", "code": "AU"},
    {"name": "Austria", "code": "AT"},
    {"name": "Azerbaijan", "code": "AZ"},
    {"name": "Bahamas", "code": "BS"},
    {"name": "Bahrain", "code": "BH"},
    {"name": "Bangladesh", "code": "BD"},
    {"name": "Barbados", "code": "BB"},
    {"name": "Belarus", "code": "BY"},
    {"name": "Belgium", "code": "BE"},
    {"name": "Belize", "code": "BZ"},
    {"name": "Benin", "code": "BJ"},
    {"name": "Bermuda", "code": "BM"},
    {"name": "Bhutan", "code": "BT"},
    {"name": "Bolivia", "code": "BO"},
    {"name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "code": "BA"},
    {"name": "Botswana", "code": "BW"},
    {"name": "Bouvet Island", "code": "BV"},
    {"name": "Brazil", "code": "BR"},
    {"name": "British Indian Ocean Territory", "code": "IO"},
    {"name": "Brunei Darussalam", "code": "BN"},
    {"name": "Bulgaria", "code": "BG"},
    {"name": "Burkina Faso", "code": "BF"},
    {"name": "Burundi", "code": "BI"},
    {"name": "Cambodia", "code": "KH"},
    {"name": "Cameroon", "code": "CM"},
    {"name": "Canada", "code": "CA"},
    {"name": "Cape Verde", "code": "CV"},
    {"name": "Cayman Islands", "code": "KY"},
    {"name": "Central African Republic", "code": "CF"},
    {"name": "Chad", "code": "TD"},
    {"name": "Chile", "code": "CL"},
    {"name": "China", "code": "CN"},
    {"name": "Christmas Island", "code": "CX"},
    {"name": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "code": "CC"},
    {"name": "Colombia", "code": "CO"},
    {"name": "Comoros", "code": "KM"},
    {"name": "Congo", "code": "CG"},
    {"name": "Congo, The Democratic Republic of the", "code": "CD"},
    {"name": "Cook Islands", "code": "CK"},
    {"name": "Costa Rica", "code": "CR"},
    {"name": "Cote D'Ivoire", "code": "CI"},
    {"name": "Croatia", "code": "HR"},
    {"name": "Cuba", "code": "CU"},
    {"name": "Cyprus", "code": "CY"},
    {"name": "Czech Republic", "code": "CZ"},
    {"name": "Denmark", "code": "DK"},
    {"name": "Djibouti", "code": "DJ"},
    {"name": "Dominica", "code": "DM"},
    {"name": "Dominican Republic", "code": "DO"},
    {"name": "Ecuador", "code": "EC"},
    {"name": "Egypt", "code": "EG"},
    {"name": "El Salvador", "code": "SV"},
    {"name": "Equatorial Guinea", "code": "GQ"},
    {"name": "Eritrea", "code": "ER"},
    {"name": "Estonia", "code": "EE"},
    {"name": "Ethiopia", "code": "ET"},
    {"name": "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "code": "FK"},
    {"name": "Faroe Islands", "code": "FO"},
    {"name": "Fiji", "code": "FJ"},
    {"name": "Finland", "code": "FI"},
    {"name": "France", "code": "FR"},
    {"name": "French Guiana", "code": "GF"},
    {"name": "French Polynesia", "code": "PF"},
    {"name": "French Southern Territories", "code": "TF"},
    {"name": "Gabon", "code": "GA"},
    {"name": "Gambia", "code": "GM"},
    {"name": "Georgia", "code": "GE"},
    {"name": "Germany", "code": "DE"},
    {"name": "Ghana", "code": "GH"},
    {"name": "Gibraltar", "code": "GI"},
    {"name": "Greece", "code": "GR"},
    {"name": "Greenland", "code": "GL"},
    {"name": "Grenada", "code": "GD"},
    {"name": "Guadeloupe", "code": "GP"},
    {"name": "Guam", "code": "GU"},
    {"name": "Guatemala", "code": "GT"},
    {"name": "Guernsey", "code": "GG"},
    {"name": "Guinea", "code": "GN"},
    {"name": "Guinea-Bissau", "code": "GW"},
    {"name": "Guyana", "code": "GY"},
    {"name": "Haiti", "code": "HT"},
    {"name": "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands", "code": "HM"},
    {"name": "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "code": "VA"},
    {"name": "Honduras", "code": "HN"},
    {"name": "Hong Kong", "code": "HK"},
    {"name": "Hungary", "code": "HU"},
    {"name": "Iceland", "code": "IS"},
    {"name": "India", "code": "IN"},
    {"name": "Indonesia", "code": "ID"},
    {"name": "Iran, Islamic Republic Of", "code": "IR"},
    {"name": "Iraq", "code": "IQ"},
    {"name": "Ireland", "code": "IE"},
    {"name": "Isle of Man", "code": "IM"},
    {"name": "Israel", "code": "IL"},
    {"name": "Italy", "code": "IT"},
    {"name": "Jamaica", "code": "JM"},
    {"name": "Japan", "code": "JP"},
    {"name": "Jersey", "code": "JE"},
    {"name": "Jordan", "code": "JO"},
    {"name": "Kazakhstan", "code": "KZ"},
    {"name": "Kenya", "code": "KE"},
    {"name": "Kiribati", "code": "KI"},
    {"name": "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "code": "KP"},
    {"name": "Korea, Republic of", "code": "KR"},
    {"name": "Kuwait", "code": "KW"},
    {"name": "Kyrgyzstan", "code": "KG"},
    {"name": "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "code": "LA"},
    {"name": "Latvia", "code": "LV"},
    {"name": "Lebanon", "code": "LB"},
    {"name": "Lesotho", "code": "LS"},
    {"name": "Liberia", "code": "LR"},
    {"name": "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "code": "LY"},
    {"name": "Liechtenstein", "code": "LI"},
    {"name": "Lithuania", "code": "LT"},
    {"name": "Luxembourg", "code": "LU"},
    {"name": "Macao", "code": "MO"},
    {"name": "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "code": "MK"},
    {"name": "Madagascar", "code": "MG"},
    {"name": "Malawi", "code": "MW"},
    {"name": "Malaysia", "code": "MY"},
    {"name": "Maldives", "code": "MV"},
    {"name": "Mali", "code": "ML"},
    {"name": "Malta", "code": "MT"},
    {"name": "Marshall Islands", "code": "MH"},
    {"name": "Martinique", "code": "MQ"},
    {"name": "Mauritania", "code": "MR"},
    {"name": "Mauritius", "code": "MU"},
    {"name": "Mayotte", "code": "YT"},
    {"name": "Mexico", "code": "MX"},
    {"name": "Micronesia, Federated States of", "code": "FM"},
    {"name": "Moldova, Republic of", "code": "MD"},
    {"name": "Monaco", "code": "MC"},
    {"name": "Mongolia", "code": "MN"},
    {"name": "Montserrat", "code": "MS"},
    {"name": "Morocco", "code": "MA"},
    {"name": "Mozambique", "code": "MZ"},
    {"name": "Myanmar", "code": "MM"},
    {"name": "Namibia", "code": "NA"},
    {"name": "Nauru", "code": "NR"},
    {"name": "Nepal", "code": "NP"},
    {"name": "Netherlands", "code": "NL"},
    {"name": "Netherlands Antilles", "code": "AN"},
    {"name": "New Caledonia", "code": "NC"},
    {"name": "New Zealand", "code": "NZ"},
    {"name": "Nicaragua", "code": "NI"},
    {"name": "Niger", "code": "NE"},
    {"name": "Nigeria", "code": "NG"},
    {"name": "Niue", "code": "NU"},
    {"name": "Norfolk Island", "code": "NF"},
    {"name": "Northern Mariana Islands", "code": "MP"},
    {"name": "Norway", "code": "NO"},
    {"name": "Oman", "code": "OM"},
    {"name": "Pakistan", "code": "PK"},
    {"name": "Palau", "code": "PW"},
    {"name": "Palestinian Territory, Occupied", "code": "PS"},
    {"name": "Panama", "code": "PA"},
    {"name": "Papua New Guinea", "code": "PG"},
    {"name": "Paraguay", "code": "PY"},
    {"name": "Peru", "code": "PE"},
    {"name": "Philippines", "code": "PH"},
    {"name": "Pitcairn", "code": "PN"},
    {"name": "Poland", "code": "PL"},
    {"name": "Portugal", "code": "PT"},
    {"name": "Puerto Rico", "code": "PR"},
    {"name": "Qatar", "code": "QA"},
    {"name": "Reunion", "code": "RE"},
    {"name": "Romania", "code": "RO"},
    {"name": "Russian Federation", "code": "RU"},
    {"name": "RWANDA", "code": "RW"},
    {"name": "Saint Helena", "code": "SH"},
    {"name": "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "code": "KN"},
    {"name": "Saint Lucia", "code": "LC"},
    {"name": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "code": "PM"},
    {"name": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "code": "VC"},
    {"name": "Samoa", "code": "WS"},
    {"name": "San Marino", "code": "SM"},
    {"name": "Sao Tome and Principe", "code": "ST"},
    {"name": "Saudi Arabia", "code": "SA"},
    {"name": "Senegal", "code": "SN"},
    {"name": "Serbia and Montenegro", "code": "CS"},
    {"name": "Seychelles", "code": "SC"},
    {"name": "Sierra Leone", "code": "SL"},
    {"name": "Singapore", "code": "SG"},
    {"name": "Slovakia", "code": "SK"},
    {"name": "Slovenia", "code": "SI"},
    {"name": "Solomon Islands", "code": "SB"},
    {"name": "Somalia", "code": "SO"},
    {"name": "South Africa", "code": "ZA"},
    {"name": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "code": "GS"},
    {"name": "Spain", "code": "ES"},
    {"name": "Sri Lanka", "code": "LK"},
    {"name": "Sudan", "code": "SD"},
    {"name": "Suriname", "code": "SR"},
    {"name": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "code": "SJ"},
    {"name": "Swaziland", "code": "SZ"},
    {"name": "Sweden", "code": "SE"},
    {"name": "Switzerland", "code": "CH"},
    {"name": "Syrian Arab Republic", "code": "SY"},
    {"name": "Taiwan, Province of China", "code": "TW"},
    {"name": "Tajikistan", "code": "TJ"},
    {"name": "Tanzania, United Republic of", "code": "TZ"},
    {"name": "Thailand", "code": "TH"},
    {"name": "Timor-Leste", "code": "TL"},
    {"name": "Togo", "code": "TG"},
    {"name": "Tokelau", "code": "TK"},
    {"name": "Tonga", "code": "TO"},
    {"name": "Trinidad and Tobago", "code": "TT"},
    {"name": "Tunisia", "code": "TN"},
    {"name": "Turkey", "code": "TR"},
    {"name": "Turkmenistan", "code": "TM"},
    {"name": "Turks and Caicos Islands", "code": "TC"},
    {"name": "Tuvalu", "code": "TV"},
    {"name": "Uganda", "code": "UG"},
    {"name": "Ukraine", "code": "UA"},
    {"name": "United Arab Emirates", "code": "AE"},
    {"name": "United Kingdom", "code": "GB"},
    {"name": "United States", "code": "US"},
    {"name": "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "code": "UM"},
    {"name": "Uruguay", "code": "UY"},
    {"name": "Uzbekistan", "code": "UZ"},
    {"name": "Vanuatu", "code": "VU"},
    {"name": "Venezuela", "code": "VE"},
    {"name": "Viet Nam", "code": "VN"},
    {"name": "Virgin Islands, British", "code": "VG"},
    {"name": "Virgin Islands, U.S.", "code": "VI"},
    {"name": "Wallis and Futuna", "code": "WF"},
    {"name": "Western Sahara", "code": "EH"},
    {"name": "Yemen", "code": "YE"},
    {"name": "Zambia", "code": "ZM"},
    {"name": "Zimbabwe", "code": "ZW"}
  ]
```

and this is how I get them.

service.ts

```
  createdCountry: Country = {
    name:'',
    code:''
  }
  country: Country[];

  getCountries(){
    return this.http.get<Country[]>('../assets/countries/countries.json');
  }
```

This is the component where I get the data to send it to the template.

component.ts

```
  getCountries(){
    this.clientService.getCountries().subscribe(countries => {
      this.clientService.country = countries;
      console.log(countries);
    })
  }
```

This is the data

[image]

Now, in my template I got this (I have to select a country and assign it to a client that's why in ngModel I have clienteService.createdClient.pais)

```
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="cardForm">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2>Ingresar Cliente al Sistema</h2>
                        <form #clienteForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addClient(clienteForm)"> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="nombreCliente" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del cliente" required [(ngModel)]="clientService.createdClient.nombreCliente" #nombreCliente="ngModel">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="pais" [(ngModel)]="clientService.createdClient.pais" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" #pais="ngModel">
                                    <option *ngFor="let country of clientService.country" [ngValue]="country">{{ country.name }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary"> 
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the select is empty.

[image]

How can i solve this?.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

client.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cliente } from '../models/clientes';
import { Country } from '../models/languages';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClienteService {

  URL_CREATE = 'http://localhost:3000/api/clients/addClient';
  URL_GETALLCLIENTS = 'http://localhost:3000/api/clients/getClients';

  createdClient : Cliente ={
    nombreCliente: '',
    pais: ''
  };
  createdCountry: Country = {
    name:'',
    code:''
  }
  country: Country[];
  client : Cliente[];
  constructor(private http : HttpClient,private router: Router ) { }

  createClient(client: Cliente){
    return this.http.post(this.URL_CREATE,client,{observe :'response'})
  }

  getClients(){
    return this.http.get<Cliente[]>(this.URL_GETALLCLIENTS);
  }

  getCountries(){
    return this.http.get<Country[]>('../assets/countries/countries.json');
  }
}
```

cliente.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ClienteService } from '../../services/cliente.service';
import { NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { Cliente } from 'src/app/models/clientes';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Country } from 'src/app/models/languages';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-cliente',
  templateUrl: './cliente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cliente.component.css']
})
export class ClienteComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    public clientService : ClienteService,
    private router : Router

  ) {

   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    this.getClients();
    this.getCountries()
  }





  addClient(form: NgForm){
    this.clientService.createClient(form.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.getClients();
        form.resetForm();
        this.router.navigate(['/addClient']);
        console.log(res);
        console.log(form);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )

  }

  getClients(){
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(
      res => {
        if(res !== undefined){
          this.clientService.client = res;
        }
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }

  getCountries(){
    this.clientService.getCountries().subscribe(countries => {
      this.clientService.country = countries;
      console.log(countries);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the options correctly loaded in the selectbox? Please post client service class and your component class.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

Don't abuse the fact the default access modifier in Typescript is public. You shoudn't assign value directly from component to service property. For a good practice you can change all properties on services as private. And when you need any access to them from outside create a method for that. Also, avoid using jQuery in Angular. This framework has his own tools to affect on the DOM. A different kinds of [*Directives*](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives)

**And about the question:**
Create "countries" property in component and assign value from it by getCountries method.

```
getCountries(){
  this.countriesList = this.clientService.getCountries()
}

<option *ngFor="let country of (countriesList | async)" [ngValue]="country">{{ country.name}}</option>
```

Comment: Agree with jQuery.. they basically shouldn't be used in conjunction unless _absolutely_ necessary.

Comment: Thanks!! , all worked. Thanks for the advices too.

Comment: @thigrand I tried to put the service in private but i can't use it in my template even with a function in the component. I search about it and i found that It's for something called  AOT that's execute during compiling the project but I don't know more

Comment: @JosePabloArancibiaLinker Yes, you shouldn't use your service in a template. If you need some data in the template, create a separate property for that in component. And mostly this is the only public property you will need.